# How can I setup a display time switch

Tags: linux, windows, display, timeout

There are several displays connected to a PC, say A B C.  How can I trigger a display reconfiguration based on a count down.  I'd like display A to be active from 6 am to 1 pm, display B from 1pm to 5 pm, and display C from 5 pm to 6 am.  The desktop should always be routed only to the active display.

Comment: All I can think of is using Task Scheduler.. but the actual command to change the display is beyond me. I read around and read that you can probably make some VBScript that does switch screen... but I haven't got the actual code. Good luck.

Comment: Adding as comment as this is a partial answer. Check this answer to change display from command line: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12329103/way-to-change-windows-7-monitors-settings-via-script - basically trigger displayswitch.exe /external or something on your task scheduler. The issue is I'm not sure how this would work with a 3-monitor setting, and displayswitch.exe is like a command line for Windows Key + P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question is tagged as both Linux and Windows, here's a Linux solution.

You need a little script that changes the display. The easiest would be ti use `xrand` which should either be installed already or is in your distribution's repositories. In the unlikely case that it is not installed, you can install it on Debian-based systems with

```
sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
```

Once `xrandr` is installed, you will first need to get the names of your displays:

```
xrandr | grep -w connected | awk '{print $1}'
 VGA-0
 DP-0
```

On my laptop, that shows that I have two available displays, the laptop's (DP-0) and a VGA screen (VGA-0). To activate only the laptop's I would run:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --off --output VGA-0 --auto
```

To activate only the VGA one and deactivate the laptop's:

```
xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --output DP-0 --off
```

I don't have a third display to connect, but if your third display is called DP-1 you can [set up a `cron` job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to switch displays at  a certain time like this:

```
## Activate VGA-0 at 6am
0 6 * * * xrandr --output VGA-0 --auto --output DP-0 --off --output DP-1 --off
## Activate DP-0 at 1pm
0 13 * * * xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output DP-0 --auto --output DP-1 --off
## Activate DP-1 at 5pm
0 17 * * * xrandr --output VGA-0 --off --output DP-0 --off --output DP-1 --auto
```

You said you want this to run when no user is logged in, since a user must always be logged in when the system is up and running, I am not sure what you mean. However, if you set the `cron` as `root` (by running `crontab -e` when logged in as `root` or with `sudo`), then the job will be run even when no normal user is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

If you couple [MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) with Task Scheduler you should be able to achieve your rotation. I haven't used it before but according to it's command line options it should work. A possible command from the command line could look like this:

```
MultiMonitorTool.exe /enable 1 /SetPrimary 1 /disable 2 3
```

There's also an option to move existing windows to the new primary display:

```
/MoveWindow
```

You may also want to look into the `/SetNextPrimary` option.

This solution is, of course, **Windows only**.

Comment: Will this work even before the user has been logged in?

Comment: Maybe. I haven't done a lot with the Task Scheduler. If there's an option to run tasks with no user logged on it might just work. Maybe somebody else can jump in here?
// edit: Looks like there's an option called "Run whether user is logged on or not". Apparently, you can't run interactive tasks but that shouldn't be an issue here.